# $v$ is an eigenvector, or $(T-\mu I )v$ is

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

> Let $T:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ be a linear operator with two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda,\mu$, and let $0\neq v \in \mathbb{C}^2$. Prove that exactly one of the following is true:
> (i)$v$ is an eigenvector of $\mu$.
>
> (ii)  $(T-\mu I )v$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda$.

My misunderstanding mainly results from the following: If $\lambda,\mu$ are distinct eigenvalues, then the minimal polynomial is divisible by $(x-\lambda)(x-\mu)=x^2 -(\lambda+\mu)x + \lambda \mu$. In particular, $T^2 -(\lambda+\mu)T + \lambda \mu I =0 \Rightarrow  T(Tv-\mu v) = \lambda (Tv-\mu v)$ which implies that (ii) is true for any vector $v$?
What am I getting wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you proved shows that $Tv-\mu v$ is an eigen vector with eigen value $\lambda$ **provided $Tv-\mu v \neq 0$**. If $Tv-\mu v =0$ then $v$ is an eigen vector for eigen value $\mu$ and we are in case (i).

Comment: At least I was really close :) Thank you!

Comment: @Bungo Thanks for pointng out.